# Why does following ARM assembly code executes even after `bx lr` line?

Tags: assembly, arm

I am calling following ARM assembly function from C. I expect it to return to C program after first `bx lr`, instead it continues down.

```
.global init_secure_monitor
init_secure_monitor:
        bx lr
        ldr r0, =msg
        bl puts
        mov pc, lr
        /* code */
        ldr r0, =msg
        bl puts
        @File ends
```

I can see 2 msgs being printed. But none should be printed. I have used both the methods to return `bx lr` and `mov pc, lr`.

What am I doing wrong?

Following is the C code, I am calling ARM from.

```
   // end secure memory                                                                              |        @ -------------------------
                                                                                                      |        movs pc, lr
    printf("_reloc_begin: 0x%x\n", &_reloc_begin);                                                    |
    printf("_reloc_end  : 0x%x\n", &_reloc_end);                                                      |/*
                                                                                                      | * Monitor Initialization
    init_secure_monitor(norm_begin);                                                                  | *
    //init_secure_monitor(boot_linux_kernel_entry);                                                   | * This is called the first time the Secure world wishes to
    //init_secure_monitor(normal_world_func);                                                         | * transit to the Normal world.
    printf("You should not come to here!\n");
```

Comment: Use a debugger. Show your C code. Make sure you did not mess up arm vs thumb mode.

Comment: arm vs thumb would just crash not print stuff...can you show the dissassembly around the caller and callee (that would support/rule out arm/thumb as well as potential other possibilities)

Comment: Are you sure that the assembler code you're looking at is the code actually being called?  (e.g. The linker has somehow linked a _different_ init_secure_monitor() from somewhere, or your modified assembler file hasn't actually been re-assembled?)